# jooq-generate - skipping JOOQ code generation

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml, jooq

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${jOOQ.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jooq-codegen</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

I changed some table in my DB so I want to generate the records, keys , classes, etc.
However every time I do that it keeps skipping the jooq code generation.

> [INFO] --- jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.10:generate (default-cli) @
>   http-gateway --- [INFO] Skipping jOOQ code generation

Which mvn cmd should I do in order to run the Jooq code generation?
For now I use :

```
mvn clean install -Dskiptests=true
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That log message:

> Skipping jOOQ code generation

Is issued when you pass the `<skip>` flag to the `jooq-codegen-maven`, [as you can see here](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/version-3.12.0/jOOQ-codegen-maven/src/main/java/org/jooq/codegen/maven/Plugin.java#L145-L148):

```java
@Override
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    if (skip) {
        getLog().info("Skipping jOOQ code generation");
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Indeed, there was a skip configuration in my pom.xml I did not paid attention. Thanks a lot !